# How to change the output of a /cmd_vel topic?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm currently working on a project with a BlueRov2 and I measured the global speed (with motion tracking cameras) of the ROV for different input in the /cmd_vel topic and now I have the equation that matches the input (in the topic) to the real speed.

What I would like to do is to change the coefficient (according to my equation) so that when I publish (for exemple) linear x=0.1 my ROV goes to 0.1 m/s (in real life).

I'm quite new to ROS and I have no idea on how to do that, could somebody advise me on what's the best solution would be ?

Thanks !

(I'm using ROS melodic btw)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376001/how-to-change-the-output-of-a-/cmd_vel-topic-?/) by [Kupofty](https://answers.ros.org/users/70707/kupofty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option is to create a new node that subscribes to the `/cmd_vel` topic and does the transformation that you're looking for and publishes the transformed data and then have the robot subscribe to that topic instead of the `/cmd_vel`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kupofty](https://answers.ros.org/users/70707/kupofty/) on 2021-04-13**:
Seems like a very good option, I'll dig into that, thank you ! =)